# How should I use the tags in Meta.AU?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, meta

I've found recently that people that ask questions in [meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) do not correctly tag their questions, and when the community reacts unexpectedly or their issues don't rise awareness to the developer team, they feel that they are abandoned or ignored, so here's how you should use the obligatory tags in meta (most of these tags are described in the excerpt, but for some *reason* nobody reads them):

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) - This should be pretty obvious. You ask a question to discuss with the community. This normally is about issues with the behavior, scope, rules, etc. Whatever that needs a consensus to change our ruleset may use the discuss tag. It's recommended that you also use tags of what you want to discuss about: tags, quality, close/reopen questions, delete answer, delete posts, scope, PSA's, etc. Anything that can be addressed by users.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) - Easy one: *"You have an idea for a new feature, or for a change to the existing functionality."* Change in the behavior of the site that needs to be addressed by SE employees. Adding/removing of some functionality, changing the design, etc. Anything that can't be addressed by users.
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) - Bugs I say! *"Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed."* With these you must include how to reproduce, what did you expected, what happened instead... details! These can only be addressed by SE personal.
- [support](/questions/tagged/support) - Whenever you need help about using the tools given. "How can you do X" kind of questions. This can be answered likewise users and developers/employees since some users know the how-to's of the site.

Remember, that even through these tags are the only obligatory/required, you can also add tags so the people following them can respond to the issue. For example, if there's some issue with the fonts/design, tag it with the [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag, so Jin can answer your concerns, otherwise your issue might go unnoticed by the people that are interested in them and can fix them (this kinda applies to the main site, too).